# Promise in Lodash map

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, lodash

I'm using Lodash to map an array. In the loop, there's a promise to get something from an external API.

```
var array = _.map(data, function (d, i) {
  getFromMyAPI(d[4])
  .then(function (results) {
    return {
      id: d[0],
      zoneLat: d[2],
      zoneLon: d[3],
      wifiLat: results.a,
      wifiLon: results.b
    }; 
  });
});
```

But then, if I do

```
console.log(array);
```

it shows, of course, an empty array. How could I get the content of this array, after the mapping is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet you've missed fact that `getFromMyApi` call requires argument from iteration... let's assume that's true.

You should treat this array as result of Promise which is chained somehow to all results of `getFromMyAPI` calls. Somehow is best done using some advanced promise library providing functional versions of classing map/reduce over promises like bluebird.

Example using bluebird:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
return Promise.map(data, function(d,i) {
    return getFromMyApi(arguments, d).then(function(r) {
        return {
            id: d[0],
            zoneLat: d[2],
            zoneLon: d[3],
            wifiLat: r.a,
            wifiLon: r.b
        }; 
    })
}).then(function(array) {
   console.log("#2", array);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot return from the map function. The array should not be empty, but should contain the Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this and it should work:

```js
var array = [];
_.map(data, function (d, i) {
  getFromMyAPI(d[4])
  .then(function (results) {
    array.push({
      id: d[0],
      zoneLat: d[2],
      zoneLon: d[3],
      wifiLat: results.a,
      wifiLon: results.b
    }); 
  });
});
```

Edited

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the argument is linked with the map iterator, I've updated the source code

Comment: In that case you need to assign the values returned. I ave edited the code.